# Profile search in PHP

Tags: php, search, recommendation-engine

I'm creating a social network. I'm trying to implement a profile search or a search engine where a profile can discover and connect to new profiles. Is there any algorithms or modules out there in PHP? Do anyone have any suggestion of how to make the search as relevant as possible please give som code example.

Any algorithms that can sort out a profile by name(both first- and last name) in a network where there are thousands of similiar names. Facebook have done this by mutual friends algorithms, but I think they have patented it, so I can't use it.

I try to implement an algorithm where profiles can discover some new profiles by giving them the most relevant search result that is at least as good as Facebook's profile search. Any tips?

UPDATE:
I made the question more specific

Many thanks! woho87

Comment: What is a "profile search" exactly?

Comment: And what criteria should used to determine which profiles to return? You'll have to define this problem more clearly or the question *will* be closed.

Comment: Profiles discovering and connecting to profiles on their own sounds spooky.

Comment: @JP19: Actually this sounds a bit like how an online dating websites sometimes work (or fail to work), trying to find the best matches between profiles, based on lists of various preferences.

Comment: The mutual friends algorithm is patented? Seriously?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I looked it up a long time ago. I might be wrong.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Take a look at this one. Iäm not the best one to read patent. But I think its this one <a href="http://www.google.com/patents?id=8i2BAAAAEBAJ&printsec=abstract&zoom=4&source=gbs_overview_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false">facebook patent</a>

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from profile where username LIKE '$username';
```

Comment: nice, i figure he would know to sanitize his data prior to querying.

Comment: I know, but I couldn't resist. :)

Comment: i think i forgot % in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want some sort of recommendation engine (like fb/orkut and many sites have).

Simplest recommendation algo - recommend friends of friends.
More - recommend people in same communities to each other.
More advanced - if you monitor what your users visit/like on your site most, then match those with common interest.

In short - some intuition mixed with creativity.

There may be recommendation engines in PHP, but perhaps not exactly for profiles. You may be able to tweak some I guess.